# What cloudant requests are considered single API Calls?

Tags: cloudant

What is considered to be a single API call to Cloudant?

To my understanding these are all single api calls respectively?:

1. Get a single document
2. Insert/update a document
3. Use the getAllDocuments function to retrieve all documents
4. Get all documents by using a view.
5. Insert documents by sending all at the same time (Bulk update)
6. Perform a search query with a search index
7. Download an attachment from a cloudant document.

Could you say that which ever function / rest request you are making to Cloudant it is considered as a single API call no matter how much data / how many documents that are transferred as the response?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. Each of the above actions can be performed with single API calls. Let's deal with each in turn:

1. Get a single document - GET /db/:id
2. Insert/update a document - PUT /db/:id
3. Retrieve all documents - GET /db/_all_docs
4. Using a view - GET /db/_design/mydesigndoc/_view/myview - Although views can be used to return a selection of documents (with startkey/endkey parameters) or to aggregate the data (by using a 'reduce' operation and optionally grouping by keys)
5. Bulk insert/update/delete - POST /db/_bulk_docs
6. Cloudant Query - POST /db/_find
7. Get attachment - GET /db/:id/:attachmentname

As a rule of thumb, limit your calls to _bulk_docs to batches of around 500. You can retrieve lots of data from views or _all_docs: Cloudant will happily spool you all the data it has. More commonly, views (or the primary index that powers _all_docs) can be used to retrieve sub-sets of the data by passing `startkey`/`endkey` parameters, or supplying `skip`/`limit` parameters.